# Updating Jersey 1 to Jersey 2 - Guice configuration - GuiceContainer and PackagesResourceConfig cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: rest, servlets, jersey, guice, jersey-2.0

I have project Guice - Jersey 1.19 project with dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-guice</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have replaced them with Jersey version 2.22.2:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squarespace.jersey2-guice</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey2-guice</artifactId>
        <version>0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${version.jersey}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
        <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

I had class which serve("/rest/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, params); but currently there is no PackagesResourceConfig and GuiceContainer.

```
public class BootstrapServletModule extends ServletModule {

     private static final String propertyPackages = GenericBootstrapConstants.JERSEY_PROPERTY_PACKAGES;

    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        super.configureServlets();

        ...

        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES, propertyPackages);
        serve("/rest/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, params);    
    }
}
```

How to serve params / replace GuiceContainer in Jersey 2?

Comment: Lean example of Tomcat 8 + Guice 4 + Jersey 2.19 - http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/lean-example-of-tomcat-82